# Is there something wrong with the distance_of_time_in_words_to_now helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Doesn't seem to be working for me. I'd open an issue on Github but I want to double check I'm not doing something stupid first. Using Rails 3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.3. [Here's the API reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words_to_now)

```
» bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.3-p194 :001 > helper.distance_of_time_in_words_to_now("2012-10-18")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
    from /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/letters-0.2.6/lib/letters/core_ext.rb:155:in `t'
    from /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:93:in `block in distance_of_time_in_words'
    from /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/with_options.rb:41:in `with_options'
    from /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:73:in `distance_of_time_in_words'
    from /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:133:in `time_ago_in_words'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Wow I actually just noticed the line about the Letters gem in the stack trace. I'll open an issue on it.

Comment: Yes me too, that's the problem not the helper method.

Comment: They mention [on this page](http://lettersrb.com/api) that there may be conflicts between letters and Rails's `t` method. I'm guessing that `distance_of_time_in_words` depends on `t` and that's the cause of this issue.

Comment: Yes I also noticed that, do you have a translation for `:x_days` in your locales file for whatever locale you are running in?

Comment: Looks to me like you have a translation for `:x_days` which interpolates for two arguments instead of one, which would explain the error.

Comment: Nope. My locales file is just the default one which comes with Rails. Still has the `"Hello World"` line in it.

Comment: Oh never mind, it looks like letters does some funny stuff. I'd suggest just following their instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`letters` gem](https://github.com/davejacobs/letters) conflicts with Rails's `t` method which is used in the `distance_of_time_in_words` helper.

See [this explanation](http://lettersrb.com/api) on the Letters website for more information.